# Ant fails with liquibase path

Tags: ant, phing, liquibase

I am trying to get phing to work nice with liquibase. But pPing gives this illustrous error (which I honestly can't find online)

```
Execution of target "update-database" failed for the following reason: PathElement (unknown) doesn't support the 'location' attribute.

BUILD FAILED
PathElement (unknown) doesn't support the 'location' attribute.
Total time: 0.1206 seconds
```

the specific commands for that are:

```
<path id="liquibasepath">
  <pathelement location="${basedir}/install/lib/liquibase.jar" />
  <pathelement location="${basedir}/install/lib/jdbc-mysql.jar" />
</path>
```

I tried searching online but there is no good documentation for using phing with liquibase. and the error's neither turn up decent results.

Comment: At first glance this appears to be an ANT issue running the liquibase ANT task. What version of ANT are you using? (I'm speculating it's ANT 1.6.5, which is quite old now). Perhaps you could update your question with the "update-database" target logic so that your issue could be reproduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer should be: This is ant, not phing. I was trying to run it with the wrong program. (there really should be some indication of this in build files ;)).

The person who commented got me on hte right track, can't accept that as an answer tho.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "path" attribute in pathelement instead of location